# Rails STI - same records for sub-sub-class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, subclass, sti

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Admin < User
end

class SpecialAdmin < Admin
end
```

I would like SpecialAdmin to have the same records/dataset as Admin model. Each SpecialAdmin record could for example have "Admin" in its type column when edited/created - any other similar solution would be fine too.

I tried this

```
self.inheritance_column :nil    # Didnt work because it fetches all records in the table
...becomes method               # Didnt get this to work either
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? STI would have both Admin and SpecialAdmin inherit from user which would then give the type of SpecialAdmin.

Comment: Baloo is right, I assume that Users and Admins will be different and have different features. It would be better for the User model to be completely separate from the Admin model

Comment: @Baloo, yes SpecialAdmin inherits Admin and User. BUT I want it to also inherit the type "Admin" form Admin model.

Comment: @Joe, agree this is just an example.